# How to move Symfony Admin Generator files to a plugin?

Tags: plugins, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I try to move my module which generated by the Admin Genrator to a plugin.

Error:

> Fatal error: Class 'BaseFooGeneratorConfiguration' not found in ...

The action.class.php includes to files:

1. fooGeneratorConfiguration.class.php
2. fooGeneratorHelper.class.php

Both classes extends of an base class (BaseFooGeneratorConfiguration,BaseFooGeneratorHelper).
The problem is that those classes only exist in the cache.

Do i need to copy the class from cache into my plugin ?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your cache after moving the module to your plugin?

```
./symfony cc
```